# How to stop Python program compiled in py2exe from displaying ImportError: No Module names 'ctypes'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, py2exe, argparse

I was wondering if this might be a compilation error or if there is something I can do to stop it from displaying. I have made an argparse program for cmd. I compiled it with py2exe and when I run it, it exacutes the program properly but always gives this error before running  the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boot_common.py", line 46, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'ctypes'
```

If it is something in my code, here is my script:

```
import argparse
import zipfile
import os
from contextlib import closing

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('ziputil '+\
    '-m <mode> -f <file> -p <output>')
    parser.add_argument('-f', action="store", dest='files', type=str,
                        help='-f <file> : Specify the files to be zipped, or the .zip to be unzipped.')
    parser.add_argument('-m', action="store", dest='mode', type=str,
                        help='-m <mode> : Zip to zip files, UnZip, to unzip files, or     ZipDir to zip entire directories.')
    parser.add_argument('-p', action="store", dest='path', type=str, nargs='?',     const=os.getcwd(),
                        help='-p <path> : specify the path to unpack/pack to.')


    return vars(parser.parse_args())

def unzipPackage(path, files):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(files, "r") as z:
        z.extractall(path)

def zipPackage(path, files):
    files = files.split(', ')
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(path, mode='w')
    try:
        for file in files:
            zf.write(file)
    finally:
        zf.close()

def zipdir(path, zip):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))



dict = parse_args()
files = dict['files']
path = dict['path']
mode = dict['mode']

if mode == 'Zip':
    zipPackage(path, files)
elif mode == 'UnZip':
    unzipPackage(path, files)
elif mode == 'ZipDir':
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'w')
    zipdir(files, zipf)
    zipf.close()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in py2exe, it'll be fixed in next release. [More Info](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.py2exe/4706)

The solution is to add `ctypes` to `bootstrap_modules` in `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py` file (line 117).

```
...
# modules which are always needed
bootstrap_modules = {
    # Needed for Python itself:
    "ctypes",
    "codecs",
    "io",
    "encodings.*",
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Does this have anything to do with the fact that _ctypes.pyd must accompany my EXE file in order to work?

Comment: @Pygmalion, I don't know, sorry!

Comment: @Victor, what next release??  Your reply is from 2014 and I have installed py2exe 0.6.9 just yesterday (1/12/19). The problem has not yet been fixed. What version are you using? Because there's no `runtime.py` in my py2exe package folder!